# Undefined Color under TikZ code

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

The Problem is '!Package xcolor Error: Undefined Color 'Black'. See the xcolor package documentation....' Perhaps is a simple mistake due to the fact that I'm a newby. Using MiKteX, xcolour package was manually installed through the manager.

```
    \documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}

    \usepackage{structuralanalysis}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{pgf}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \point{x}{3}{0};
        \point{y}{3}{3};

        \draw[line width=1.5pt, fill=Black]
        (x) rectangle (y);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome, try `black` instead of `Black`.

Comment: @Johannes_B thanx, working for black. But what is with other colors like RubineRed or mixtures like RubineRed!25!White

Comment: The `xcolor` manual has an overview of what colors are defined with which option.

Answer (score 6):

`LaTeX` is case sensitive, therefore `black` is different from `Black`. If you want to use `Black`, you need to load `xcolor` with options `svgnames` or `dvipsnames`, both define this color with capital `B`.

But if you try `\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}` an error for clashing options will appear beacuse `pgf (TiKZ)` load `xcolor` with different options. In this case it's better to pass `xcolor` options through documentclass command.

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt,svgnames]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{structuralanalysis}
%\usepackage{xcolor} % pgf already loads it
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \point{x}{3}{0};
    \point{y}{3}{3};

    \draw[line width=1.5pt, fill=Black]
    (x) rectangle (y);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanx! for Black and simple colors it worked, but not for RubineRed or RubineRed!25!White, which cofuses me.

Comment: @Miri Does https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors help you?

Comment: @Miri `RubineRed` is defined with `dvipsnames` option, if you add it, you could use all named colors. Take a look a [page 38 in `xcolor`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/xcolor#page=38).

Comment: @Miri, if the answer solved your problem, please accept it --- marking the ticks you have under the answer's score. This is the way of saying "thanks" here... ;-)