# LaTeX Produces a Tikzpicture with the Color I Want---but with Error Messages Indicating the Color is Not Defined

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, color, tikz-pic

I have written some code to produce a `tikzpicture` with a lavender color that I later want to add some text to.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=1pt}
    } %
]
\node[
preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
pencildraw,draw,fill=lavender!35,text width=0.89\textwidth,inner sep=5mm,align=justify] 
{\fontsize{14}{18}\selectfont {\bf ``.'' \vskip 1pt \hfill \emph{---}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the error messages:

[image]

But, (surprise! surprise!), the box with the color I am trying to produce:

[image]

QUESTION: How can this be? The error messages indicate that Latex does not know the color I am asking for---yet it produces the color I want. Is there a way I can determine what the RGB or CYMK numbers are for the displayed picture? Such tikizpictures will be part of a larger document and I prefer not to run the code with error messages even though it is producing what I want.

THANK YOU.

Incidentally, the same thing happens if I use the `color` package instead of the `xcolor` package. And, if I ask the fill color to be *lavender* instead of *lavender!35*---I get a black for a color.

Comment: Hmmm... That patch seems quite gray (`black!35`). Btw, off topic, but `\bf` is deprecated since more than 20 years...  

Comment: You can see the list of predefined colors at page 38 here: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf, I can't see `lavender` there

Comment: As @Rmano says, the fill color of that node is gray. I'm guessing it just reverts to the default black somehow. (TikZ already loads `xcolor` by the way, so the `\usepackage{xcolor}` is actually redundant.)

Comment: There is a `Lavender` color if you pass the option `svgnames` to xcolor (notice the uppercase L). I do not know how `tikz` calls it, so maybe you need a `\PassOptionToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}` before loading tikz (can't check now), see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51488/option-clash-with-xcolor-and-tikz. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296500/undefined-color-under-tikz-code

Comment: @Rmano Would you know, offhand, if there is a way in LaTeX (or perhaps some other means) to determine the RGB numbers given a colored box of unknown color such as the one I posted? I suspect not, but perhaps there is some other available means to do that---If you know of any way that could be done, I think that would be very useful.

Comment: @mchristian you can use a color picker (plenty of them for every OS, I think), but  this is not so easy. Conversion from a theoretical  color in a document to rgb can be quite complex depending on the output device.  Look for color managed devices...

Comment: @Rmano Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- remove loading `xcolor` package
- add option `svgnames` (or `dvipsnmaes`) to options of `book` document class
- instead `lavender` use `Lavender` for color name:

```
\documentclass[12pt,svgnames]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
 decorate,
 decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=1pt}
    } %
]
\node[
preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
pencildraw,draw,fill=Lavender!35,text width=0.89\textwidth,inner sep=5mm,align=justify]
{\fontsize{14}{18}\selectfont {\bf ``.'' \vskip 1pt \hfill \emph{---}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]